# Chartjs Overlap click function doesnt work

Tags: chart.js

I have a simple line chart and I have problem when two or more points are too closer. The problem is: The tooltip show one point and the click function is for other point.

In this exemple you can see that when I click on the first point on the red line (value 2) the click event is for the black line (value 0)

Exemple:
https://codepen.io/ataufo/pen/NexppY

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("lineChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Stock A",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(225,0,0,0.4)",
      borderColor: "red", 
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      pointBorderWidth: 0.1,
      pointHoverRadius: 6,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      data: [2, 59, 80, 81, 56],
      spanGaps: false,
      datalabels: {
        enabled: true,
        allowOverlap: true,
        display: true,
        listeners: {
          click: function(context) {
            alert(context.dataIndex + " Red line");
          }
        }
          }
    }, {
      label: "Stock B",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "black",
      borderColor: "black", 
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      pointBorderWidth: 0.1,
      pointHoverRadius: 6,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      data: [0, 20, 60, 95, 64],
      spanGaps: false,
      datalabels: {
        enabled: true,
        allowOverlap: true,
        display: true,
        listeners: {
          click: function(context) {
            alert(context.dataIndex + " Black Line");
          }
        }
      }
    }

  ]
};

// Chart declaration:
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  showTooltips: false,
  type: 'line',
  data: data
});
```

Does anyone have one idea to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly reference dataset `0`. You need to pass the dataset index like so:

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
  var activePoints = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
  //console.log(activePoints);
  if (activePoints[0]) {
    var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
    var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];

    var label = chartData.labels[idx];

    // change the following line...
    //var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];
    // to this:
    var value = chartData.datasets[activePoints[0]._chart.tooltip._active[0]._datasetIndex].data[idx];

    var url = "Mês:" + label + " Valor: " + value;
    alert(url);
  }
};
```

***Edit:*** Fully working example.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("lineChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
      var activePoints = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
      console.log(activePoints);
      if (activePoints[0]) {
        var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
        var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];

        var label = chartData.labels[idx];
        //var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];
        var value = chartData.datasets[activePoints[0]._chart.tooltip._active[0]._datasetIndex].data[idx];

        var url = "Mês:" + label + " Valor: " + value;
        alert(url);
      }
    };


var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Stock A",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(225,0,0,0.4)",
      borderColor: "red", 
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      pointBorderWidth: 0.1,
      pointHoverRadius: 6,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      data: [2, 59, 80, 81, 56],
      spanGaps: false

    }, {
      label: "Stock B",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "black",
      borderColor: "black", 
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      pointBorderWidth: 0.1,
      pointHoverRadius: 6,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      data: [0, 20, 60, 95, 64],
      spanGaps: false
    }

  ]
};

// Chart declaration:
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    tooltips: {
         enabled: true
    }
  }

});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #666;
}

#lineChart{
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
<!--       Chart.js Canvas Tag -->
      <canvas id="lineChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VictorSoares I did check. Try the fully working snippet I've just edited into my answer. This is a direct copy of your [codepen](https://codepen.io/ataufo/pen/NexppY), changing only the one line I specified.

Comment: I see but you can click between points black and red and see. I am clicking on the black dot (Jan: 0) and the alert shows the red dot (Jan: 2). The clicked value is not synchronized with the tooltip display

Comment: I tried to use the datalabels plugin for that but I had the same problem. The original code for that is on my original post. That codepen exemple was another shot to the same problem

Comment: There is a 1 or 2 pixel overlap of the datapoints that is causing the problem. The datapoints are so close together you could probably only fix this by reducing the radius of each to minimise the overlap.

Comment: Maybe in this case but I have to deal with other points closer then that ones. So I have to deal with overlap and show exacly the same point that displays on the tooltip.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the `onclick`?

Comment: The onclick will call a ajax function and show some data from the point.

Comment: See the edit to my answer - I've updated the line to pull the dataset index from the active tooltip object - it should now match the tooltip displayed.

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thank you very much!